# Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import site module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, fatal-error, python-3.9

Here is the error i recieve randomly when my code runs:

```
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 603, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 590, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 365, in addsitepackages
    if os.path.isdir(sitedir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/genericpath.py", line 42, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I have looked and the site.py file does exist in the python3.7 directory. would upgrading to python3.9 fix this issue?

EDIT: There is no keyboard or mouse plugged into the raspberry pi. I don't know how its keyboardInterrupting.

Comment: The issue seems to be a KeyboardInterrupt error that happened during the import of the site module based on the provided output.

Comment: Related python issues: [issue19983](https://bugs.python.org/issue19983), [issue14228](https://bugs.python.org/issue14228).

Comment: what could cause the keyboard interrupt? i don't have a mouse or keyboard plugged in?

Comment: If this is intermittent, then it sounds like a hardware problem.  I'm guessing that something is causing your hardware to think that a keyboard related event has occurred, and that event is causing the OS to halt the `stat` operation that it is running on your Python program's behalf.